# Dynamically changing the value of a label from another class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created my own MessageBox class. It's pretty simple, it has a label and a button to close it.

In my System_Functions class, I'm validating if a username exists or not:

```
Prompt prompt = new Prompt();
...
if (checkUsername == 0) {
                    prompt.Show();
                    return false;
                }
```

The Prompt class contains the custom message box. However, I don't know how I go about changing the label dynamically as I plan to use it on other warnings as well.

I know the code is supposed to be `label.Text="Insert string here";` but I have know idea how to implement it. I use `prompt.Show();` to show the custom message box, but how do I pass parameters?

This is my Prompt class, I haven't added a method that takes string arguments yet to change the label:

```
public partial class Prompt : Form {
        public Prompt() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be one way:

```
public partial class Prompt : Form {   

            public Prompt(string message) {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.labelforMessage.Text = message;   // Use this string as label text
            }

            private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
```

Then from other classes you can Pass the message when you create the Prompt object. Remember C# BCL does similar in MessageBox.Show() method and its overloads

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm very new to C# and it's working now